# Twitter Bootstrap - Buttons appear all the same size

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap

G'day helpers!

I am struggling with following problem:

```
<a href="..." class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> edit</a>
```

and

```
<a href="..." class="btn btn-large"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> edit</a>
```

appear in the complete same format. Both are in the large-button-style. But my first button should appears as a smaller button (not the same size as the large button). Has anyone an idea why that's happen? When I try with -tags the problem appears too. I could not find an appropriate solution in the internet so far.

I hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Cheers

Comment: can you provide html from parent elements

Comment: Just to make sure you've loaded bootstrap and css is being applied, can you add "btn-primary" and see if the buttons are blue?

Comment: I do appologize. The reason why it did not work was as follows: I have a second css created for a design. There I defined the parent .btn tag (or better say: I overwrite it) and then my big css was not in charge anymore. I do appologize for my question as it was my fault. Many thanks all contributors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btn-mini` and `btn-large` work totally fine for me. Please see the other html or css to check whether the problem is because of some other elements. sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/Uup3x/)

Comment: Many thanks, I will check my CSS, apparently the problem needs to be there somewhere. Thank you for the fiddle-link, I did not know that this is existing.

Comment: I do appologize. The reason why it did not work was as follows: I have a second css created for a design. There I defined the parent .btn tag (or better say: I overwrite it) and then my big css was not in charge anymore. I do appologize for my question as it was my fault. Many thanks all contributors!

Comment: To anybody coming across this years later. It's `btn-lg`, `btn-xm` and `btn-xs`.

Answer (score 1):

It was the case of bootstrap.css being overridden by our own site.css as it turns out. Had to copy .btn-sm... from bootstrap.css to our customised site.css and it started working like a charm.